# disallow particular email extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to disallow `.co email extension`, below is my regular expression which i am using.

```
/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-+]*(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-+#]+)*(\#[_a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?!\.net.net|\.som|\.coom|\.om|\.como|\.ney|\.fuck|\.com.com)+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,4})))$/"
```

When i try to add `.co` to list, its failing for `.com` and others too.

```
/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-+]*(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-+#]+)*(\#[_a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)
    *@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?!\.net.net|\.som|\.coom|\.om|\.como|\.ney|\.fuck|\.co|\.com.com)+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,4})))$/"
```

The below format should fail.

```
something@some.co
```

Comment: Shortest sub-string should be the last in the list.

Comment: /^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-+]*(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-+#]+)*(\#[_a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?!\.net.net|\.som|\.coom|\.om|\.como|\.ney|\.fuck|\.com.com|\.co|)+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,4})))$/"

Comment: Still failing...

Comment: If you look at the link, its failing for something@some.com which is valid.

Comment: I would suggest having a whitelist and a blacklist, something like: `var whitelist = /\.com$/; var blacklist = /\.co$/; function is_valid(email) { return true if whitelist.exec(email); return false if blacklist.exec(email); return true; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expression engines are satisfied at the very first occurrence. Saying that, shortest sub-string should be the last in the list, always.

And one another thing to care about is checking for end of subject string immediately:

```
^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-+]*(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-+#]+)*(\#[_a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?!(?:\.net.net|\.som|\.coom|\.om|\.como|\.ney|\.fuck|\.com\.com|\.co)$)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,4})))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/ot1bCF/1)

Comment: @Shane Do you want `.co` to exist nowhere or only at the end. @revo this would fail if `.co` is not the terminating substring. - `something@some.co.bz`

Comment: I don't see if it does matter since OP's checking for e.g. `\.com\.com` already.

Comment: Yup. That's a doubt for me too.